# Function to detect if specific value exists in an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array that looks like this:

```
userInterests [
  {
    "Status": "Interested",
    "$id": "-JncIGjhkuEx1Hq6Lzax",
    "$priority": null
  }
  {
    "Status": "Interested",
    "$id": "-TDIEGjhkuEx1Hq6Lzax",
    "$priority": null
  }
]
```

I need a boolean function that returns true or false if the id matches, so a function like this:

```
function isAnIDInArray(id) {

}
```

so that

```
isAnIDInArray(-JncIGjhkuEx1Hq6Lzax);
```

Would return true

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/k6yucv9h/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function have to loop through all objects in the array and check evry id. So something like this:

```
function isAnIDInArray(id, array) {
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        If(array[i].$id == id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Not sure if you can use '$' in javascript syntax tho.